# очистка файлов определенного формата на bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Необходимо очистить содержимое файлов формата .log в папке /c/ss.
В файле sss.sh прописал

cd /c/ss/
: > *.log

Погуглил truncate и мне выдало : > filname.txt

Нужно очистить файлы определенного формата, в данном случае .log
Пробовал очистить содержимое файла, но пришлось выписать целое название файла, но мне нужно очистить 788 файлов формата .log каждые 5 минут. С интервалом в 5 минут я разобрался, у меня запускает скрипт каждые 5 минут, но скрипт не может ничего почистить

Скрипт будет лежать в debian8, поэтому можно написать и многое другое, не смотря на MSYS2 на win10.
Но я не понимаю что.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а может Вам нужно удалить файлы?

Comment: `truncate --size 0 /path/to/files/*.log`?

Comment: @KoVadim удалять нельзя. ибо падет игра на серваке

Comment: @EOF спасибо за помощь)